# PassportJS Google oauth2.0 login/register

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, oauth-2.0, passport.js

I've been trying to get the `google oauth login system` to work on multiple ports and found issues of saving the data (from backend to frontend) when redirecting (most tutorials do this on the same port which got me confused). I understand how to get data from backend on frontend (through axios) but am `confused how to send data from backend to frontend`, and so I found [this tutorial](http://%3Chttps://medium.com/free-code-camp/how-to-set-up-twitter-oauth-using-passport-js-and-reactjs-9ffa6f49ef0%3E) similar to what I'm looking for. (I tried to adapt this to use google oauth instead of twitter)

However, in [this tutorial](http://%3Chttps://medium.com/free-code-camp/how-to-set-up-twitter-oauth-using-passport-js-and-reactjs-9ffa6f49ef0%3E) during the google redirect, I'm getting an error:

> Error: Failed to serialize user into session

On googling, most say it's related to the `serializeUser` and `deserializeUser` functions (which I however have). So I'm quite hard-stuck and am hoping to find a fix.

Here's my code:

```
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user.id);
});

// deserialize the cookieUserId to user in the database
passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
  User.findById(id)
    .then(user => {
      done(null, user);
    })
    .catch(e => {
      done(new Error("Failed to deserialize an user"));
    });
});

passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy(
    {
      clientID: keys.googleClientID,
      clientSecret: keys.googleSecret,
      callbackURL: "http://localhost:5000/auth/google/redirect"
    },
    (token, tokenSecret, profile, done) => {
      // find current user in UserModel
      console.log(profile);
      const currentUser = User.findOne({
        googleId: profile.id
      });

      // create new user if the database doesn't have this user
      if (!currentUser) {
        const newUser = new User({
          name: profile.displayName,
          screenName: profile.displayName,
          googleId: profile.id,
          profileImageUrl: ""
        })

        newUser.save()
          .catch((err) => console.log(err));

        if (newUser) {
          done(null, newUser);
        }
      } else {
        done(null, currentUser);
      }
    }
  )
);
```

Thanks for reading this and helping!!